# React accessing object properties and displaying them to the screen

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In my react app I fetch some data from an api like this:

```
function PlayerPage() {
  interface PlayerDataType {
    id: number;
    handle: string;
    role: string;
    avatar: string;
    specialAbilities: null;
    stats: null;
  }
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState<Array<PlayerDataType>>([]);

  //Fetch all forms from database
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch('https://localhost:44326/api/Players/1')
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
      })
      .then((data) => setPlayer(data))
      .then(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, []);
```

If the player object isn't set yet then I just display that the page is loading, otherwise display the page, like this:

```
if (isLoading === true && !player) {
    return (
      <Page>
        <PageTitle>Loading...</PageTitle>
      </Page>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Page>
```

In the return body after the player has loaded I would like to display `player.handle` however when I try it like this:

```
 return (
      <Page>
        <PageTitle>{player.handle}</PageTitle>
      </Page>
    );
```

I get the error:

```
Property 'handle' does not exist on type 'PlayerDataType[]'.ts(2339)
```

But if you look back up at the original code block I provided you can clearly see that the property 'handle' does indeed exist on the type PlayerDataType[].

What is happening here? Why doesn't this work?

Here is the entire page if that helps:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Page } from './Page';
import { PageTitle } from './PageTitle';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

function PlayerPage() {
  interface PlayerDataType {
    id: number;
    handle: string;
    role: string;
    avatar: string;
    specialAbilities: null;
    stats: null;
  }

  const { id } = useParams();
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [player, setPlayer] = useState<Array<PlayerDataType>>([]);

  //Fetch all forms from database
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    fetch('https://localhost:44326/api/Players/1')
      .then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.json();
        }
      })
      .then((data) => setPlayer(data))
      .then(() => setIsLoading(false));
  }, []);

  console.log(id);
  console.log(player);

  if (isLoading === true && !player) {
    return (
      <Page>
        <PageTitle>Loading...</PageTitle>
      </Page>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <Page>
        <PageTitle>Player Name</PageTitle>
        <PageTitle>{player.handle}</PageTitle> //This not working
      </Page>
    );
  }
}

export default PlayerPage;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your PlayerDataType[] is an array, which means handle does not exist.

Try

```
<PageTitle>{player[0].handle}</PageTitle>
```

This will get you the first element in your array.
If you wish to display several players. Use a map

Something like this

```
return(
    {players.map((e, i) => {
                        console.log("I am looping through the list of players");
                        return <PageTitle event={e} key={i} onClick={() => presentModal(e)} />
                    })}
)
```

Comment: Here is an better example from another question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45857698/loop-through-simple-array-of-objects-in-react

Comment: Ok this is kind of embarassing. I reused that PlayerDataType[] from a page that did have multiple players but this one only has 1 and should not be an array... Whoops. So I made PlayerDataType not an array ````useState<PlayerDataType>();```` . Thank you!

Comment: You could try to change the PlayerPage to include the PlayerData as a Prop. Then you won't need to use an array :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52504925/passing-props-into-react-component

Answer (score 1):

Your player state is a array of `PlayerDataType`. Then, the handle property not exists in the array...